# What are the differences between spam-flag-nuking and moderator manually validating spam flags?

Tags: support, flags, spam

What are the differences when a post is

1. deleted by Community ♦ for having 6 spam flags from regular users or one spam flag from a ♦ moderator (and consequently, locked by the Community user)
2. deleted by methods other than red-flag-nuking (by ♦, 20k+ users or by Community ♦ through user deletion/destruction), with pending spam flags manually approved by ♦ moderators

One thing I know is that the -100 rep penalty is not applied on case 2, but what else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a post is deleted by spam flags:

- the post is deleted by Community<sup>1</sup> and locked
- users who can see deleted posts<sup>2</sup> see a message that this was deleted as spam or offensive, and they have to click a link to see the text
- the user gets -100 rep
- the information feeds an IP block

If a post is deleted by a moderator or three 20k users or from review:

- the post is deleted by named users
- if there were "enough" validated red flags, users see the warning message/link; if not, they see the text
- it doesn't affect reputation or the IP block

I *believe* "enough" is two rather than one, but I'm not certain.  As a moderator I am careful to flag-delete spam rather than just deleting it, and I advise other moderators on my teams to do likewise.

<sup>1</sup> If any users cast delete votes, their names appear here too (with Community casting the final vote).

<sup>2</sup> Except moderators, who always see the post.

Comment: So no automatic punishment is applied if a post has its spam flags manually validated by a ♦?

Comment: Right -- the post has to actually be deleted by spam flags to impose the penalties.  A moderator who agrees with a spam flag should add a spam flag, not just mark the flag helpful.

Comment: There can be a combined situation, when high-rep user already voted to delete, and then post has been deleted as spam by flagging. In the result the list of users which votes contains both: high-rep user and Community user.

Comment: @älёxölüt thanks; good point.  I've edited that in.